# Search bounding rectangles (axis aligned) for a given query point in 2 dimensions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geospatial, spatial-index

I have a set of very many axis-aligned rectangles which maybe nested and intersecting. I want to be able to find all the rectangles that enclose/bound a query point. What would be a good approach for this?
EDIT : Additional information-
1. By very many I meant ~100 million or more.
2. The rectangles are distributed across a huge span (span of a country). There is no restriction on the sizes.
3. Yes the rectangles can be pre-processed and stored in a tree structure.
4. No real-time insertions and deletions are required.
5. I only need to find all the rectangles enclosing/bounding a given query point. I do not need the Nearest Neighbors.

As you might have guessed, this is for a real-time geo-fencing application on a mobile unit and hence -
6. The search need not be repeated for rectangles sufficiently far from the point.

I've tried KD trees and Quad-Trees by approximating each Rectangle to a point. They've given me variable performances depending on the size of the rectangles.
Is there a more direct way of doing it ? How about r trees?

Comment: How many is "very many?" Can you pre-process the rectangles to build a data structure for querying? Will you be checking many points against the same set of rectangles? You might start with the naive method in any case. It could very well be fast enough for your purposes, and if it's not then at least you have a known working algorithm against which you can test your optimizations.

Comment: Hi Jim, what exactly do you mean naive methods? Also, I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I guess that the rectangles you have are known in advance and they aren't likely to "move", "shrink" or "span". If I am correct, then you should consider a bulk-loaded R-tree (or its variants).

Comment: The naive method is to sequentially search the entire list, which obviously is not practical for a list of 100 million rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the R*-tree data structure.

In contrast to many other structures, **the R*-tree is well capable of storing (overlapping) rectangles**. It is *not* limited to point data. You will be able to find many publications on how to best approximate polygons before putting them into the index, too. Also, it scales up to pretty large data, as it can operate on disk, too.

R*-trees are faster when bulk loaded; as this can be used to reduce overlap of index pages and ensure a near-perfectly balanced tree, whereas dynamic insertions only guarantee each page to be at least half full or so. I.e. a bulk loaded tree will often use only half as much memory / storage.

For 2d data, and your type of queries, a quadtree or *grid* may however work just well enough. It depends on how much local data density varies.

Comment: I'm going to give R* TREES a try using BOOST library.

Comment: I understand that the search in R tree must be a query box, however, I want to search for all the rectangles that necessarily contain a given query point. Is this possible? Will making the query rectangle a point (by making it small enough) give the desired results?

Comment: You can perform various kinds of searches, including nearest neighbors, **overlap**, containment etc. - In your case, you want overlap with your query point, I guess.

Comment: well, if this is possible , then I needn't look further. I'm going to delve right into it. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting good documentation on the BOOST Rtree implementation. The official documentation is particularly lacking for spatial indexes. Got anything that could be helpful?

Comment: I have never used it. There were a few questions on it here, but I don|t remember seeing answers - probably a too small user base, ask at the boost mailing list maybe?

Comment: I've decided to use the sqlite implementation of R*Tree. It allows me to query as per my requirement simply using inequalities. However, the tree is always parsed top-down, and I would like to change that to bottoms up parsing from the last result. Any pointers on that?

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing" a r-tree? Trees are not parsed.

Comment: Please excuse my terminology. As I understand, the R-tree always starts the search from the parent node. I want to optimize this for my application performing subsequent searches in a bottom-up fashion since the subsequent results are almost always going to be nearby 'fences'.

Comment: The only way to reach a leaf is by starting at the root and navigating through the tree. Your idea is similar to knn joins, but even these start at the leaf and go down levelwise.

Comment: The first time the search executes, it goes down the tree and finds the right 'fence' , in subsequent searches, it traverses up from the last result till it finds a parent node that could contain the right 'fence' . The search then traverses downward again. Does this sound absurd?

Comment: That is what an rtree search looks like, yes. Find the coordinates, then expand to the surroundings as far as you want. But you'll have to restart for your next search (and that doesn't hurt much, you will usually have the index pages in cache anyway)

Comment: Thank you. I'm fairly new to all of this. I plan on implementing this on a microcontroller for a realtime application and hence I'm concerned about the performance.

Comment: For real-time and not too large data sets (that fit in main memory), don't neglect primitive grid-based approaches. They waste more memory, but are much simpler to implement and can pack a lot of updates.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a quadtree. (Posting from mobile so it's too much effort to link, but Wikipedia has a decent explanation.) You can split at the left, right, top, and bottom bound of any rectangle, and store each rectangle in the node representing the smallest region that contains the rectangle. To search for a point, you go down the quadtree towards the point and check every rectangle that you encounter along that path.

This will work well for small rectangles, but if many rectangles cover almost the entire region you'll still have to check all of those.

Comment: What about kd-tree and r-trees?

Comment: Both of those could also work. R-trees might be a little more effort for possibly better performance, both effects due to paging; that probably depends on the actual workload, so you'd have to implement both to be sure. Kd-trees (for K=2) are pretty similar to quadtrees I'd expect.

Comment: @Erik , I've thought along similar lines. How do you propose I choose the splitting plane? Also, how do I take care of intersecting and nested rectangles?

Comment: As a first try, you could take the set of all top and bottom boundaries and split at its median. Same for horizontal splits. This defines a tree of rectangles, one for each node of the tree. These rectangles are not the same as the rectangles you're storing! Nesting and overlapping automatically works if you store each rectangle in the bottom-most node for which the corresponding tree rectangle contains it.

Comment: @ Erik - I've decided to try out R* tree for now. Though , I will experiment using KD tree to efficiently store and search for rectangles in the near future. I will post an update when I do.